# Running python script from excel vba using Shell does nothing

Tags: excel, python-2.7, vba

I am trying to run a python script in excel VBA like this:

```
Shell("python " & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CreateVolsurface.py -d ""10 Sep 12""")
```

but it does nothing. If I watch the task manager, a python process doesn't even get created. If I debug and copy the string created in the code above and paste it into command prompt it runs perfectly.

The python script takes a date (as a string) as a parameter and creates an image file.

Any idea why this would not work or how I could debug it?

I've also tried this:

```
Shell ("python CreateVolsurface.py -d ""10 Sep 12""")
```

and this:

```
ret_val = Shell("python " & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CreateVolsurface.py -d ""10 Sep 12""", vbHide)
```

but they also do nothing.

---

The issue was that `shell()` in vba starts cmd.exe in it's default folder and not in the active folder of the current workbook. In my python script I had relative path references which was an issue. To solve this I used the os module in my python script to change the current directory at the start.

Comment: Hi, I took a different approach, I don't shell, I use a "gateway class".  So called gateway because it opens the rich world of the Python ecosystem to the Excel VBA Developer  http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/python-vba-curve-building.html

Comment: @smeaden this solution is six years old so I'm sure there are a lot of great new options. I couldn't really follow what you mean by gateway class from your link. Can you explain it a bit further please?

Comment: Gateway class = a COM class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the path to python.exe, or you may need to add the path to your %PATH% environment variable.

Try the following to verify Shell is working and step through with the debugger:

```
ret_val = Shell("notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

If that works, then you should try specifying the path:

```
args = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CreateVolsurface.py -d ""10 Sep 12"""
ret_val = Shell("C:\python27\python.exe " & args)
```

If you need to check if python is in your %PATH% environment variable, the Process Explorer (procexp.exe) utility from sysinternals can show you all of the environment settings for a running process.

Comment: Thanks, actually looks like the error was elsewhere but using normal focus helped me find it. Shell("") is launching cmd.exe BUT, and I guess this makes sense, it starts it in C:\Users...\Documents and not in the ActiveWorkbook.Path. I'm sure I'll figure out how to change that. Oh and the error was because I was reading a file using relative path name in the python script so it couldn't find it as was running from wrong directory :/